# Developing USDT wallet on ERC20 tokens

Tags: ethereum

I am new to the Ethereum network. I want to develop a wallet (on JavaScript and Node.js) for USDT based on the ERC20 token on the Ethereum network.

Can it be built on JavaScript and Node.js?

Also USDT is a tether-based cryptocurrency whose value is about equal to US$1. So for example, USDT on the ERC20 network works on Ether addresses. So if I send 1 ETH to that address then will it be automatically converted to current ETH value to USDT? (i.e, approximately 273$)?

I am learning Ether on [Ether's  documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/), so do I need anything else to learn and create a USDT and ETH wallet?

Comment: Are you looking to just create a frontend for a user to connect their wallet to (e.g. with metamask), or are you trying to create a sort of smart wallet contract ? 

Plain JS or your framework of choice will be fine for the frontend- you'll need the web3.js collection of libraries.

Comment: @SimonR I want to actually build only  a USDT wallet based on ERC20 token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be built using JavaScript and Node.js.

And if you send 1 [ETH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum) (US$273) to some other address, you will receive 1 ETH, not 273 USDT. The value is not converted automatically. You'll have to exchange your 1 ETH against 273 USDT.

Comment: Thanks.So if i have 1 ETH then i can convert to USDT? how tether.to works?? It deposits  USDT from USDT wallet..

Comment: you can exchange ETH against USDT, but you can not convert them.